# Using a parameterisation of Lagrangian and conserved quantities to reduce dimensionality

Tags: classical-mechanics

**Nb**. This is a past exam paper question I am attempting to answer

Given the following Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}mg_{ij}\dot x^{i}\dot x^{j}-U(x^4)+\lambda(g_{ij}x^ix^j-a^2)$$
$(a)$ Specify any continuous symmetries and use Noether’s theorem to construct the
corresponding conserved quantities.

$(b)$  Use the conserved quantities to show that the system is effectively one-dimensional,
and derive the effective potential and effective Lagrangian of the resulting onedimensional system.

**Answer**

Using Noether's Theorem the conserved quantity is
$$J_{ij}=p_ix^{j}-p_jx^i$$
Also, the energy is
$$E=\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^Tg\dot x+U(x^4)$$
I realise I can reduce the dimensionality by one if I use a parameterisation of $S^3$ however this is very computational, is there a faster way to eliminate dimensions?